# Django counting objects of a related object

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models defined: `User, Article, ArticleVisit` and I want to extract the total number of views a user has combined from all articles.

Something like (which obviously fails):

`user.articles.visits.count()`

Django 1.7 in case it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArticleVisit.objects.filter(article__user=user).count()
```

Comment: That's assuming that **ArticleVisit** has a foreign key relationship with the article model and that has a foreign key relationship with the User model